# ¿Cómo poner esto en forma de tabla PHP y HTML?

Tags: php, html

Hola lo que necesito es que los campos no se vean en lista si no esten en forma de tabla lo que pasa es que no más no puedo nesecito que aparezcan en tabla ya sea en 4 y 4 o 5 y 3 (incluyendo el botón) para el usuario no tenga que bajar tanto la página.
El contexto es el siguiente en el cuadro de arriba tengo dos datos Grupales e Individuales y cada uno tiene sus propios campos si le das click a uno cambian los campos y viceversa necesito ayuda para ponerlos en tabla los campos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilosMenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/crearCita.css">
    <title>CREAR CITA</title>
</head>

<body onload="datos();">
    <?php include "header.php"?>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row espacio">
      <div class="col-md-2  offset-md-5" id="cuadro">
         <form>
                  <div class="form-check">
            <label><input type="radio" name="cita" value="1" checked>GRUPALES</label>
          </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
            <label><input type="radio" name="cita" value="2">INDIVIDUAL</label>
          </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>


    <div class="row espacio" id="grupal">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="formGrupal">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">CLAVE GRUPAL</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claveGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">NOMBRE GRUPAL</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">FECHA DE REGISTRO</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaRegistroGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">HORA DE REGISTRO</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="horaRegistroGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">RESPONSABLE RPE</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="responsableRPEGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">FECHA DEL GRUPAL</label>
                        <input type="date" id="fechaDelGrupal" step="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">VALOR</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" id="botonInsertarGrupal" class="btn btn-success" value="Registrar">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="container" id="individual">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div id="formIndividual">
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Individual">CLAVE UNICA</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="claveUnicaIndividual" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">

                        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Individual">NUMERO CITA</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numeroCita" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label id="texto1Individual">NOMBRE DE CITA</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numeroCitaIndividual" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Individual">RPE PROFESOR</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="RPEIndividual" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off">
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Individual">FECHA DE REGISTRO</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaRegistroIndividual" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Grupal">HORA DE REGISTRO</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="horaRegistroIndividual" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="texto1Individual">FECHA DE LA CITA</label>
                        <input type="date" id="fechaCitaIndividual" step="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="submit" id="botonInsertarIndividual" class="btn btn-success" value="Agendar">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section id="informacion">
        </section>

    </div>


    <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/crearCita.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es la estructura de una tabla html, lo que tenes que hacer es insertar cada uno de tus input dentro de un td diferente como te lo hice en el ejemplo. Cabe aclarar que deberias aplicarle los estilos que usas tambien. Saludos.

```html
<table class="egt">
<tr>
<td>Grupal/Ind</td>
<td>Clave grupal</td>
<td>Nombre grupal</td>
<td>Fecha de Registro</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="cita" value="1" checked>grup</label><br><input type="radio" name="cita" value="1" checked>ind</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="claveGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaRegistroGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"></td>
</tr>
</table>



<table class="egt">
<tr>
<td>Grupal/Ind</td>
<td>Clave Grupal</td>
<td>Nombre Grupal</td>
<td>Fecha de Registro</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="cita" value="1" checked>grup</label><br><input type="radio" name="cita" value="1" checked>ind</label></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="claveGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaRegistroGrupal" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Con los de "deberias aplicarle los estilos que usas tambien" a que te refieres??

Comment: A los archivos css que estas utilizando

Comment: Ya pude muchas gracias!!